# Prevent deadlock in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, deadlock

I need to create a method in .NET Core to run 3 different parallel threads:
Thread n.1 will check in db table T1 if condition1 is satisfied and in that case will add to table T a new row in "waiting" status; the same for Thread n.2 with table T2 and condition2.
Thread n.3 will run all "waiting" rows of table T.

What's the best way to avoid deadlock and concurrency issues?

My code:

```
public void Run()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Thread1);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Thread2);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Thread3);
}

private SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public void Thread1(object state)
{
    semaphoreSlim.Wait();
    try
    {
        using (var db = new BDbContext())
        {
            var t1 = db.T1.ToList();
            if (condition1(t1))
            {
                var t = f(t1);
                db.T.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}

public void Thread2(object state)
{
    semaphoreSlim.Wait();
    try
    {
        using (var db = new BDbContext())
        {
            var t2 = db.T2.ToList();
            if (condition2(t2))
            {
                var t = f(t2);
                db.T.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}

public void Thread3(object state)
{
    semaphoreSlim.Wait();
    try
    {
        using (var db = new BDbContext())
        {
            var tt = db.T.Where(k => k.IsWaiting);
            //Do something with tt
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: The best way to avoid concurrency issues is to have none. Do you even see a difference when you do all that in sequence?

Comment: If operation1 and operation2 are independent, then maybe you can run them in two separate Tasks on which you `await WhenAll` and then start operation3?

Comment: i think this is more of a database design issue than .net core; but you may want to look at putting your entire logic in a stored procedure than encapsulates the work-to-be-done, where you have control over locking. Then, the .net code would execute the procedure

Comment: In your example all methods will be executed sequentially, because you limit semaphore to 1 thread. So there is no point to running them in separate threads like so. If you write down your data dependencies (e.g. what methods use the results of other methods) you can see which method do not depend on the others, and run them in parallel.

Comment: @nevermind you're right about semaphoreSlim. As I wrote in my comment to Jonash answer, my threads are all independent but the issue is that they have to interact with same table T. How can I isolate these interactions?

Answer (score 0):

a good way to prevent deadlocks is to ensure all locks are taken in the same order from all threads. This might be easy if all locks are in the same class, but can be very difficult to achieve in the whole program. One way to approach that problem is to be very restrictive with what you do while holding a lock. I.e. avoid raising events or call arbitrary methods, only call code that you understand well, and that only takes locks no other class could possibly hold.

Another good rule is to never block the UI thread, this is also a resource that is held, and can cause deadlocks.

These rules are not foolproof, but will likely help at avoiding some problems. I'm not going to try to cover "other concurrency issues", since it would probably amount to a whole book.

But that does not seem very relevant for your specific example.

1. All three methods take the same semaphore, so only one will run at a time, but in arbitrary order. So there is no benefit from using multiple threads.
2. `Thread1` and `Thread2` are independent, so could run concurrently just fine. I assume `Thread3` is intended to be run *after* thread 1/2?
3. Most databases (but not *dbcontext*) handle concurrency internally, so are usually fine to call from multiple threads or processes. I think there are ways to cause internal deadlocks in the db, I do not think that is possible for simple queries like this, but I'm not a database expert.
4. I do not see the point in using a semaphore with a count of one over a lock. A lock should do the same thing in a simpler way. Semaphore has some async support that could be used, but that is not used here.

I would probably suggest just to skip all the manual threading stuff. Use a database with async support and rewrite your code to use async calls. Your code could then look something like this:

```
Task t1 = DoT1Stuff();
Task t2 = DoT2Stuff();
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
await DoT3Stuff();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. My threads are all independent, I would say that the only issue is that they could add a row in the same table T or read from T. I could run task 1 and task 2 to retrieve rows to add to T, then after "WhenAll" submit these rows in T table, but how can i prevent deadlock with thread 3 which could probably interact with table T? I think this is my problem: table T.

Comment: @nonloso That is not a deadlock. That is a ordering issue, or perhaps a race condition. The best way to solve that is a better database design. If that is not possible, read my answer on how to enforce ordering.